# Variance of the sum of a random subset

Tags: combinatorics, variance

Let $A$ be the group of whole numbers in the range $[0, n)$.
We choose uniformly at random from all subsets of size $k$ ($0 < k < n$).

The mean of the sum of the subset is $\frac{n-1}{2} k$. What is the variance of the sum?

(In fact, I need the variance of the average of the subset, but given the variance of the sum it is easy to calculate)

Comment: The mean is not $\frac{nk}{2}$. Did you perhaps mean the range $(0,n)$, or the range $[0,n]$?

Comment: When you say "randomly choose a subset of size $k$", do you mean "choose uniformly at random from all subsets of size $k$"?

Comment: Edited the question accordingly. Thanks for the corrections!